# fetch google map data from external website

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, xml, google-maps

Is this possible to read or parse google map data(i-e    http://www.ukairquality.net/MicrosoftMapFast2.aspx ) from external website 
I just want to get data from this and store this data in my sql...

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
        XmlDocument XmlDoc = new XmlDocument();
        XmlNamespaceManager XmlNs = new XmlNamespaceManager(XmlDoc.NameTable);

        XmlNs.AddNamespace("def", "http://earth.google.com/kml/2.0");

        string url = "http://www.ukairquality.net/MicrosoftMapFast2.aspx ";
        XmlDoc.Load(url);
        //XmlDoc.Save(MapPath(@"~\xml\test.xml"));

        XmlNodeList Nodes = XmlDoc.SelectNodes("//def:coordinates", XmlNs);

        foreach (XmlNode Node in Nodes)
        {
            textBox1.Text= Response.Write(Node.InnerText + "<br />");
        }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sure you can load data from other webstes, but the URL you give is not XML.  You'll get an error if you try to parse it as XML.

If you want to get the data from this UK site, then you'll need to look at their javascript and use string functions to get the parts you want.

Comment: yup i confusing the two different things now its clear